# Cumulative brownian expectation

Tags: integration, stochastic-calculus

Calculate $\mathbb{E}\left(\Phi\left(W_{t}\right)\right)$ where $W_{t}$ is a brownian motion and $\Phi$ the standard normal cumulative distribution.

Solution using integrals:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\mathbb{E}\left(\Phi\left(W_{t}\right)\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left(\frac{-u^{2}}{2}\right) d u\right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} \exp \left(\frac{-x^{2}}{2 t}\right) d t \\
\mathbb{E}\left(\Phi\left(W_{t}\right)\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Phi(x) \Phi^{\prime}(x) d x=\left[\frac{\Phi^{2}(x)}{2}\right]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{gathered}
$$
I don't understand why the first integral is structured like that and also the inner part is $\Phi(x)$ but what is $\Phi^{\prime}(x)$ in the first integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first integral is structured like that because, by definition,
$$
\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left(\frac{-u^{2}}{2}\right)\,du.
$$
I hope this tells you what $\Phi'(x)$ is. Also note that, for any function $f(x)$,
$$
\mathbb E(f(W_t))=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} \exp \left(\frac{-x^{2}}{2t}\right)}_{(*)}\,dx.
$$
because the pdf of $W_t$ is (*) which obviously equals $\Phi'(x/\sqrt{t})/\sqrt{t}\,.$
Your second equation looks wrong. It should be
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(\Phi(W_t))&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Phi(x)\,\Phi'(x/\sqrt{t})\frac{dx}{\sqrt{t}}\,.
\end{align}
To solve this I prefer to write it as
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\mathbb E(\Phi(W_t))&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Phi(ay+b)\,\Phi'(y)\,dy\,.
\end{align}
In your case $a=\sqrt{t},b=0,y=x/\sqrt{t}\,.$ Eq. (1) is
$$\tag{2}
\mathbb P\{X\le aY+b\}
$$
where $X,Y$ are two independent standard normal random variables. Obviously,
$$
Z:=\frac{X-aY}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}
$$
is a standard normal RV. Therefore, (2) is
$$
\mathbb P\{Z\le b\}=\Phi(b/\sqrt{1+a^2})\,.
$$
In your case $b=0$. Therefore (1) and (2) equal $1/2\,.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you also clarify why equation $(1)$ is equivalent to equation $(2)$?

Comment: By the independence of $X,Y$ their joint PDF is the product of two one-dimensional PDFs. Write (2) as a double integral and realize that you can integrate over $x$ from $-\infty$ to $ay+b$.